# How to insert data in to struct

Tags: arrays, json, go

```
type Orders struct {
    data []struct {
        href    string `json:"href"`
        order_id string `json:"order_id"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
```

How do I insert data in to data array struct in orders struct?

```
orders.data = append(orders.data, orders.data{ href: r.Host+r.URL.Path+"/"+orderid, order_id: orderid})
```

it errors. What's wrong?

Comment: Unlreated to your question but you have json struct tags on your fields which implies you want to marshal/unmarshal this to/from JSON. If that's the case, you *must* export the fields (exported field names start with a capital letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see [append built-in function](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append).

`orders.data` is not a type. `data` is a field with an anonymous struct type of the struct named `orders`. So you should either name that anonymous struct to something like:

```
type HrefAndOrderID struct {
    href     string `json:"href"`
    order_id string `json:"order_id"`
}
```

And use

```
HrefAndOrderID{"dummy_href", "dummy_order_id"}
```

when appending.

Otherwise you can again use the same signature of that anonymous struct to append:

```
orders.data = append(orders.data, struct{href string `json:"href"`; order_id string `json:"order_id"`}{ href: r.Host+r.URL.Path+"/"+orderid, order_id: orderid})
```